# Single Page Apps JumpStart - ScriptBundle not bundling new scripts

Tags: asp.net, breeze, single-page-application, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-optimization

I have been using Single Page Apps JumpStart on PluralSight developing a new app with all these new JavaScript libraries.

I keep running into this reoccurring issue where in each chapter I add the new scripts that I need as part of the bundle. In this instance it is Q and breeze. But for some reason when I debug my application and I go to the network tab of my browser, they are not retrieved. Because of this breeze.EntityQuery is undefined in my datacontext.js, giving me a JavaScript error.

When including a new script file as part of my script bundle, is there anything else that I need to do to make it work? I have checked the scripts folder of my application and I have all the required files in the folder. I have checked for typos and everything appears to be correct.

Comment: Are you adding to bundles on a per request basis as opposed to statically on app start?

Answer (score 1):

When I change the ASP.NET bundles I often rebuild the server .NET project first. Then make sure the browser has cache disabled. In Chrome I do this from the developer tools || settings. Then refresh the browser while the dev tools are open. This will cause the browser to get fresh files from the server.